# How can I add custom php include() file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my wordpress theme, there is a page name pre-registration. 
if I take there any HTML form, that work but I need a congig.php file for MySQL query for this page.
Please help me to add a include(); file at that page.

Comment: *congig* or **config**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If It is not a template and you are making something like plugin or your code is directly or indirectly belongs to `fucntions.php` you can use include as you do in core PHP. If It is an template part use `get_template_part()` instead , if you can see some error or you have noticed nay problem, please let me know.